# Flag a new question as duplicate across communities for old, unmigrated questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

Due to the introduction of communities on Stack Overflow, older answers are generally left on the parent website and cannot be used to close questions in communities:

[image]

For example, I'd like to close [this new question on the DBA community](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213213) using [this old (answered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date).

I'd like to suggest an augmentation to this logic to allow flagging posts as duplicates across communities when the older question was created before the community of the current question was created.

Comment: Just leave a comment like: _Cross duplicate/Related: <link>_

Comment: Why the downvotes? Without an explanation when I have tried following all the rules I have spent time making myself aware of, they only serve to discourage contribution.

Comment: On Meta votes usually indicate agreement/disagreement with the proposed feature change or addition. Downvotes on this question would indicate that people don't want the functionality you describe, not that you broke any rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Allow cross-site duplicate closures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151729/allow-cross-site-duplicate-closing/305032) and its related/linked questions on the Meta Stack Exchange site, there are several reasons already why we don't close as duplicates across the network sites.

What you can do instead:

Generally, the best option is just to leave a comment linking the related cross-site duplicate. That way, like in your example, someone who finds the question on DBA can follow the link to SO and find the additional answers. A good way to write these comments:

> A similar question was asked and answered on Stack Overflow: [How to convert number of week into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date)

Or even more simple:

> Cross-Network dupe: [How to convert number of week into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date)

Or just:

> Related: [How to convert number of week into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date)

Alternatively, if the duplicate you find on a different site is really really good (Like if you find a question on DBA that is a duplicate of a question on SO and the one on SO has a really good answer), such that you believe that site will benefit from having the material added to their own site, then another option is to simply answer the question on the site with a similar answer to that of the duplicate you found, and link to the original answer as part of your answer.

Do not do this second option if you are not familiar with the site and what is considered on topic for an answer there. The site may have a different focus warranting a different kind of answer. For example, a similar question may be asked on both the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) and the [Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions). You might see that and want to share an answer about the legality of a workplace behavior found on the Law Stack Exchange with the question asking about how to deal with that behavior on the Workplace Stack Exchange, however [Legal Advice is off topic for the Workplace SE](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/what-is-legal-advice), so that answer would not necessarily be a good fit for Workplace even though the questions are very similar. Make sure you know the sites you're working with before considering posting a similar answer to the related question, lest you end up posting off topic answers or answering off topic questions.

If you do decide to post an answer, make sure though to write a full complete answer (not just links to the original answer), and to properly cite any references you use. Even with proper citation, if you find yourself using a significant portion of the existing answer, consider making the answer into a community wiki so that it doesn't appear that you are trying to use the work of the user who posted the answer in the duplicate you found just to get upvotes.